# How to retrieve inner text of a xpath?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I want the inner text from a xpath

I'm trying this, but so far I cannot get the text

```
  const download = await frame.$x(xpath);
  const downloadText = await download[0].getProperty('textContent');
  console.log(downloadText);
```

That throws as a result, the following

```
JSHandle {
...
    _targetType: 'page',
    _sessionId: '14CCB014112B47319CA8A1C810F23B18'
  },
  _remoteObject: { type: 'string', value: '20200129_1500.zip' },
  _disposed: false
}
```

I want to retrieve the value that's in _remoteObject, I've tried almost everything I've found and nothing seems to work for me.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine!

```
  const text = await (await download[0].getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jsonValue()`:

```js
const download = await frame.$x(xpath);
const downloadText = await download[0].getProperty('textContent');
console.log(await downloadText.jsonValue());
```

Alternatively, you can just pass the element to `evaluate`:

```js
const downloadText = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, download[0]);
```